# ASP.Net MVC - "Cannot Create Instance of an Interface"

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now, and I'm at a dead end, so maybe you guys can help.  Note that this is not related to this question.

I am using Entity-Code First within MVC3.  I must have done something dodgy to one of my objects, because when it first tries to create the database and populate it from my `Seed` function, this error occurs (the `Seed` function is never actually called, but the database and the tables **are** created).

The exception is thrown deep in the system:

```
>   mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache = true) + 0x63 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic) + 0x46 bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.DefaultDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type serviceType) + 0x25 bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService<System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory>(System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver resolver) + 0x3d bytes  
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.SingleServiceResolver<System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory>.Current.get() + 0x7e bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = {System.Web.Routing.RequestContext}) + 0x72 bytes  
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = {System.Web.Routing.RequestContext}) + 0x2a bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) + 0xb bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(System.Web.HttpContextBase context = {System.Web.HttpContextWrapper}) + 0x108 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x57 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x95 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = true) + 0x4c bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x13e bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) + 0xad bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request}) + 0x1a2 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x7d bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x47 bytes  
    WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process() + 0x17b bytes 
    WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection conn = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}) + 0x6c bytes 
    [Appdomain Transition]  
    WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(object acceptedSocket) + 0x83 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x2d bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x5a bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x147 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x2d bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

I only have one object at the moment.  Note, as I said earlier, it **is** created in the database:

```
// class Category
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryID")]
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ListOrder { get; set; }

    // left/right
    public int TreeLeft { get; set; }
    public int TreeRight { get; set; }
}   // eo class Category
```

This is my `DbContext`-derived class:

```
// class ModelContext
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Models.CMS.Category> ContentCategories { get; set; }

    // property to get the object context
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        }
    }


    // OnModelCreating
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }   // eo OnModelCreating

}   // eo class ModelContext
```

Not much going on there.  And finally, my initializer.  The `Seed` function is never called:

```
// class ModelInitializer
public class ModelInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ModelContext>
{
    // seed
    protected override void Seed(ModelContext context)
    {
        var catRepo = Models.CMS.CategoryRepository.Instance;

        // Root category node
        context.ContentCategories.Add(catRepo.CreateRoot());

        // Test data
        Category home = catRepo.Add(new Category { Name = "Home", ListOrder = 10 });
        Category news = catRepo.Add(new Category { Name = "News", ListOrder = 20 });

        catRepo.Add(new Category { Name = "Current News", ListOrder = 10 }, news);
        catRepo.Add(new Category { Name = "Older News", ListOrder = 20 }, news);
    }   // eo Seed

}   // eo class ModelInitializer
```

You may or not require more information, and I will provide it obviously.  I have no idea where to begin to look.  The error might not even be related to my models, but anyway.  I Note that it occurs in the MvcRouteHandler, I have not done anything special here and if I ignore the exception, I end up in my action handler for a HomeController.  I get an error here because the database is not seeded (As `Seed` was never called).

Oh, and if it helps, the initializer in `global.asax.cs`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DbDatabase.SetInitializer<ModelContext>(new ModelInitializer());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

EDIT: The controller looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.CMS.CategoryRepository repo = Models.CMS.CategoryRepository.Instance;
        List<Models.CMS.Category> cats = repo.GetAll();
        return View();
    }
```

The error occurs **before** it gets to this handler, however.  Some code in that `GetAll()` call then gets an error because the database is not populated (the Initializer was never called).

Comment: And what does the action / controller look like? When exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, thanks for your response.  I've edited it to include the controller method.  The error occurs before it hits this method.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, If you set a breakpoint in the global.asax.cs on the first line in `Application_Start`, does it go pass the `SetInitializer` line?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, yes it does.  Incidentally, before that, I get a "Culture Not Found" exception, but not sure if that is related or not.  I stepped over that `SetInitializer` line just fine.

Comment: Can you add your controllers constructor? It seems like you're passing in an interface to the constructor and the default dependency resolver is trying to instantiate it, but that's obviously not possible.

Comment: @TheCloudlesSky, I do not define one.  That `Index()` method I've put in the post, constitutes the entirety of my controller.

Comment: @Moo - if you're debugging this application, where is it throwing the exception? Are you SURE that this is the controller being called? I don't think it is, according to the exception.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, I make sure the database is deleted and the app newly compiled to force an initialization, and then hit with F5.  As things start to happen I get 2 x "Culture not found" exceptions, I ignore and continue, then the break point hits the `Application_Start`.  I debug through this, everything is fine.  I hit F5.  I get the "Cannot Create instance of an interface" exception.  If I hit F5 at this point it hits my breakpoint in the controller, and my Seed function has never been called.

Comment: @Moo - If you could, could you upload the project somewhere where I could take a look?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky , I appreciate your help.  I put it at http://anyhub.net/file/1KkP-fleetchoice.com.au.zip .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the project. First, to start fresh without any model issues, I set the `ModelInitializer` to inherit from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` because I don't want any stale data in the database each time I debug.

When I ran the application, I was getting a null exception in the `Add()` method of the `CategoryRepository`. I think you may have a misunderstanding of the repository pattern. Currently, you're using a static repository, which IMO is bad to do. You're also creating a new model context in several places, which you should avoid by passing it in to the repository as a parameter. Ideally your interface for the Category repository should look something like this:

```
public interface ICategoryRepository
{
    void Add(Category category);
    void Remove(Category category);
    List<Category> GetAll(int parentId = 0);
    Category GetRoot();
    Category Get(int id);
}
```

Then inside your implementation of the repository would be something like this:

```
public class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
    private readonly ModelContext context;

    // Here we pass in the context so that it can be used by methods.
    public CategoryRepository(ModelContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    #region ICategoryRepository Members

    public void Add(Category category, Category parent = null)
    {

        if (parent == null)
        {
            parent = this.GetRoot();
        }
        // Snipped the stuff here.

        // Finally add to the current context.
        this.context.ContentCategories.Add(category);
    }

    // And all other methods...
}
```

I've made some significant changes to the project, so I hope they make sense for the repository pattern. You can find the [updated project here](http://anyhub.net/file/1Koc-fleetchoice.com.au_updated.zip). After I changed this, I was getting an exception about relationships - so I think your best be would be explain how you're trying to model categories (some form of a tree structure...) and I can help you from there. Also, be sure to clean your project and make sure the database is empty. Cheers!

Comment: Thankyou for your commitment to this issue.  I never got as far as the Add() method due to the errors that happened before.  Can you tell me why the static repository is such a bad idea, and why passing a context in is worthwhile?  Thanks again for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: @Moo - No problem. Having static repositories and hard-coded contexts increases coupling and removes any possibility for testing your code. Also - keeping static objects around for a web project is just wrong. A "unit of work" is exactly what the "context" is in EF-CF. In web, it's usually *one* unit of work (aka context) per *request*. Therefore creating them inside the action is *much* better than "deeper" (such as the repository). You shouldn't think of a repository just as an in-memory list that you can query and perform operations on. It should only work with the UoW, not save it.

Comment: (continued) So ideally you'd use a dependency injection framework such as Ninject, AutoFac, or Castle Windsor and "inject" them into the controller's constructor. Maybe that's a little down the road for you right now. The idea of having one "unit of work" is essentially like a database transaction - do a bunch of things and then *SaveChanges()* (in the controller's action). Hope this helps explain things better.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky , thanks for your advice but how do you cache thing properly without a static?  Do you throw things in to session or application objects?  For example, in my "Category" Repository it caches the root note as this will be accessed frequently.  In fact, in other areas it will make sense to cache other things.  Is it best therefore, in these cases, to wrap non-static objects around other things?

Comment: In the web sense, you can use the Cache property on the HttpContext. In your case, you could do exactly as you did before with the root, but don't make anything static. So, you'd new up the repository, and then when Root is called, it'll query the current context and store it in an instance variable. You don't need to preoptimize this by caching objects in a static variable. Let me know if this needs more explanation and I can code a sample.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, Ok, I got it.  I'm mainly used to none "on the fly" applications where stuff is around for a while as opposed to the blink of any eye.  I've modified by repository accordingly.  I'm assuming, therefore, that you had no interface exceptions?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, also thanks so much for the modified project.  I have encorporated your suggested changes and understand why they are necessary.  Especially the part about not needing RAW sql.  I guess I was unsure how this worked under the hood.  These "Categories" are a bit of a test-drive using hierarchal data.  The Application that is being ported has a hierarchy of thousands.  Will this mean that the raw SQL be better, will that LINQ generate a whole ton of UPDATE when 2 were necessary?  Also...

Comment: ... I noticed you create the root in the Initializer and passed it to the other categories as the parent.  Now as you've stated, E-CodeFirst has not yet persisted the root, so it does not have an ID yet.  This means that the subsequent Add() calls will fail.  How can I get around this as ideally I'd like the category added to be persisted then and there, otherwise it is difficult to add a parent, then a child, then a child.  Is there anyway to populate a test database like this?

Comment: @Moo-Juice - What do you mean by interface exceptions? EF is smart enough to generate the correct update statements for the. Now that I think about it, executing this statement entities that you selected, but it would generate N update statements (the good thing though is that it's inside a transaction!). I'd suggest you benchmark this later on to see if it causes too many problems. In that case you could then go the custom SQL route.

Comment: To answer your last question - you'd *ideally* try to avoid working directly with IDs for relationships. So instead of `category.ParentCategoryID = parent.CategoryID` it would be `category.ParentCategory = parent.Category`. And the same should go for querying: `where c.ParentCategory == parent.Category`. I'm on my mobile, so I can't fully test this, but it *should* work (let me know if it doesn't). Regardless, you're right about needing to know the ids when they have yet to be persisted. Hope this helps!

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky, thanks for your assistance.  Things are working now.  I got around the problem of adding nodes to parents in the `Seed` function by manually calling `SaveChanges` which worked nicely.  Secondly this whole interface error, I think, was a red-herring and something that is occurring internally and nothing to do with me (like the `CultureNotFound` exception).  Thanks for continued help and assistance!

Comment: @Moo - No problem - good luck with it, if you have any more questions about this - let me know. Cheers!